# Find records with same city and salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is my query for finding matching records, but same salary condition is not working.

I want multiple same city and same salary records

```
select distinct 
    t1.Name,
    t1.Salary,
    t1.City
from 
    Test t1,  
    test t2 
where
    t1.City = t2.City and 
    t1.Salary <> t2.Salary
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. I suppose you can remove at least some of your tags...

Comment: Why MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle? Tag only those products which you are using!

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. And table definitions.

Comment: You should avoid ancient-style joining by `,` - write what exactly you want from server: inner, outer, cross, full join and it's conditions.

Comment: i used inner join but its not working

Comment: is this homework question ? Hint : use GROUP BY

Comment: group by not working

Comment: Can you specify your server first? which out one of three mentioned?

Comment: I have Sql Sever 2014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find The Same City and same salary record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553882/how-to-find-the-same-city-and-same-salary-record)

Answer (score 0):

**t1.Salary<>t2.Salary** should be t1.Salary = t2.Salary

to solve this *"But Same Salary Condition Not Working"*