# How to find The Same City and same salary record

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to find multi same city and same salary record by using temp table

Comment: Please explain more and  use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for better responces.

Comment: You have to explain your problem better, isnt clear what are you asking.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
    (
     City nvarchar(20),
     Salary decimal(9, 2)
    )

insert  into @t
        (City, Salary)
values  (N'New York', 65000),
        (N'London', 68000),
        (N'Sydney', 59000),
        (N'Sydney', 59000),
        (N'Tokyo', 66000)

select  *
from    @t as t
group by t.City,
        t.Salary
having  count(1) > 1
```

Comment: what is N are use for what??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Comment: This code is working for any MS SQL Server Version since 2008. Do you have an earlier version installed?

Comment: yes its working now can you tel me i am also want to displaying one More field without group by

Comment: If you have a new question then please post the new question. But before you do so, please read the comments by @juan-carlos-oropeza and Neeraj above. Also, please include an SQLfiddle or at least a sample table with sample data (as I have done for you in my answer)! Thank you.